# How to display files created during a specific date range

Tags: filemanager

How does one display files within a file system comprised of multiple subfolders that were created within a date range (say Jan 1 - Mar 31) without resorting to the command line. Is there a file manager with this capability.

Comment: But it's so easy from the command line.

Comment: My computer is a tool. I am not a hobbyist. UNIX commands are cryptic and inconsistent. I know the Linux community derides "Windoze", but Windows has enabled this kind of file search in their file manager for decades. There are several Linux file managers available, and I hoped that someone could tell me if one enables a file search by date, so that I don't have to find it by trial and error.

Comment: Dolphin on kde does, if balloo is enabled. But you should work on your attitude if you want help here.

Comment: I really like the Gnome desktop in Ubuntu. Is Dolphin compatible with Gnome? Or is there a Gnome variant? I started my programming career working on VAX/VMS machines, and DCL (Digital Command Language) is far superior to UNIX. The commands are more attuned to natural language and the command qualifiers (switches in UNIX parlance) are consistent from command to command. UNIX is far harder to learn and use than VMS.

Comment: Dolphin is compatible (though it looks a bit out of place on gnome), but balloo which allows dolphin to do what you want is tightly integrated into KDE. Dolphin imho, when used on KDE, is the best filemanager across all platforms I have worked with (split view, terminal integration with F4, Filter bar) but I would not run in on GNOME. I have not used GNOME in a while so I can not help you.

Comment: You may want to have a look at some of the following tools: http://www.fsearch.org/,  https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-search-tool/, http://www.twotoasts.de/index.php/catfish/, https://github.com/DoTheEvo/ANGRYsearch

Comment: Though I have tried none of them

Comment: I tried Dolphin, and could not find a date range capability. After reading several critiques, I tried Krusader next. The "Search" function in Krusader (in the Tools menu) enables a user to search by a date range or within the last X number of days, and also to search all subdirectories below your current location. Very straightforward, and you don't have to resort to the command line. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and installed Krusader from the Ubuntu Software Center.